# Is it good Python style to write a function that has no effect other than potentially raise exceptions?

Tags: python, coding-style, error-handling

Sometimes I find myself writing Python code that looks like this:

```
def check_stuff(param):
    if condition1(param):
        return "condition1" # These might be enum values, etc., instead of strings
    if condition2(param):
        return "condition2"

def func(param):
    cs = check_stuff(param)
    if "condition1" == cs:
        raise Exception1(param)
    if "condition2" == cs:
        raise Exception2(param)      
    #...
```

Here, the return value of `check_stuff` is only used to decide what exception to raise. Let's imagine that this is true of every time I call `check_stuff`, probably because I only call it once. Would it be better style to just raise the exceptions in `check_stuff` itself?

```
def check_stuff2(param):
    if condition1(param):
        raise Exception1(param)
    if condition2(param):
        raise Exception2(param)

def func2(param):
    check_stuff(param)
    #...
```

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, a function that just raises an exception is OK.

You can easily have functions like `ensureWellFormed(email_address)` or `http_request.ensureUserLoggedIn()` that raise well-documented exceptions. This de-clutters code, and many high-profile projects, e.g. Django, do use this style here and there.

If you use this approach, make sure your exception objects carry enough context data to understand and report what happened in an exception handler. *'User has no access to the URL requested'* is nigh useless; *'User joerandom has no access to URL /foo/bar'* is quite useful.

<sup>**No, a parameterless function working with global state is a bad idea.**
Your example code shows functions that check global state. Referring to global state implicitly is usually a *very* bad idea. It creates hard-to-detect dependencies. If you happen to alter global state, especially implicitly, it creates weirdest, hard-to-detect bugs. Code that refers to global state is hard to test and hard to refactor, too. The global-state approach may appear easier now, but in a slightly longer term it will bite painfully. Note how in my examples above either a parameter is passed to a function for checking, or an object instance is used (which is also passed to a method as the `self` parameter).</sup>

Comment: A good example: The `requests` library lets you raise exceptions from bad requests with [`Response.raise_for_status()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes).

Comment: Feel free to use that example in your answer. In particular, I'm fond of naming functions like `raise_for_x()` or `raise_if_y()`.

Answer (score 1):

### No, it would be worse

- **functions should tell what they do.** With a good naming, your `check_stuff` function indicates what it does. It should therefore be named e.g. `checkConditionsValid` depending on what it actually does. I suppose your function `func` also returns something or has some side effect in case that the conditions are. If not, *that* would be a design flaw, not the `check_stuff` function.
- **Use dependency injection.** Instead of heaving `check_stuff` rely on some global variable, pass the conditions to it as arguments. It not only makes your code easier to reason about it also makes it more readable.

Comment: Well, `foo` also doesn't say what it does, but it's still a function name in plenty of examples. The global vars are bad practice, but I'm actually not sure that's what he was asking about.

Comment: `foo` does say what it does. It does what would be suitable in your real world code. It is therefore not intended to be used in real world code. ;) Using global vars influences how functions are named. You are right, it is not specifically what he asked for, but it may help understanding the better naming and the reason for that naming.

Comment: Your entire point is assuming he's posting real-world code. You're likely wrong, *and* he didn't ask to understand naming conventions. He asked about exception conventions.

Comment: The apparent use of global variables (which I did to keep the examples short) was so heinous that several people commented on it, so I removed it.

Comment: @Katana314 Those two things belong together. A function should be named different when throwing an exception or returning a value or executing a side effect. In my opinion these information should be included in the answer.

Comment: See, I'm fine with adding extra helpful information **when it's obvious that it's not just laziness for an example** (ie, "Oh, that should be a ===, not a ="). I sometimes use `eval` or `document.write` if it keeps a brief example short. Even misinterpreting that and saying "Hey, don't use eval" is usually fine, but the real problem is I don't really think you answered the central part of the question; is it acceptable to have a function whose only purpose is to raise exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Maybe

It can work to externalize *validation* logic as long as it is not externally visible and is used to enforce preconditions.

Say you have an object that operates on a database connection, and most of its functions require that the connection be set up and initialized. Rather than checking the connection and conditionally throwing an exception in each function, have one function that checks the connection which is called by each method that uses the connection before it is used. This realizes [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and helps ensure consistency.

For this to work well, the validation method and the state it checks should be private to the object. This prevents other objects (including subclasses) from causing it to violate preconditions.